# Print on both sides with Epson printer

Tags: printing, printer

Trying to print on both sides with my Epson L4160 printer by selecting Print on Both Sides:
[image: t]

Printer prints first side and reports warning:

```
"Load same paper as selected in your print settings"
```

What does it means and how to ask printer print on both sides?

Comment: Complete guess - A4/US Letter sizing conflict. Prefs are set for one, other is loaded in the paper tray.

Comment: You need to remove the printed page (one side), turn it over and print on the other side.

Comment: @John - it's a duplex printer; shouldn't be necessary, but idk what settings tell it to print d/sided.

Comment: If Duplex, then Author you should check the Printer Settings (printer control panel).

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happend to me on ET-2760 and was solved by untickinig 'choose paper source by PDF page size' when printing.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that the printer prints 1 side before giving an error. However, the error indicates that, while the driver requests A4 paper (of unknown type), the printer does not know that you have that size/type loaded.

The printer needs to be told the paper size and type (plain, coated, gloss, etc) from its control panel, as explained starting at the bottom of [page 40 of the User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1362454/Epson-L4160-Series.html?page=40#manual):

> On the control panel, set the size and type of the paper you loaded in
> the rear paper feed. To select an item, move the focus to the item
> using the arrow buttons, and then press the OK button.
>
> Note: You can
> also display the paper size and paper type settings screen by
> selecting Settings > Printer Setup > Paper Source Settings > Paper
> Setting.

One possible cause of getting the error only on the 2nd side is if the document uses different paper sizes for different pages. In Word that can be done after inserting a Section Break in the document. If that is your problem then there is no solution, except making both pages the same paper size. Of course, Word will re-paginate the document when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Printer Properties and Change the Document Size to A4. Usually this message appears when the paper size doesn't match with the printer setting.

Your document is A4 sized. SO you have to change it to A4 from the printer settings.

Answer (score 0):

had the exact same problem with you on my L4160. called epson care centre and what they told me to do which fixed the issue was:
(for windows) computer settings > devices > Printers & scanners > manage > Printing preferences:
Under layout, select "flip on long edge". And under "print on both sides".
Under Advanced, select A4 paper size.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

I set the size paper like A4, and it didn't work. After that, I changed to set the size paper on printer and document size "Letter" or "U.S Letter." Now, it doesn't show an error "Load same paper as....." Good luck!